# Struts2 Jquery Grid Multiple Action transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have one form which contain two grids and both grid for loading data action is different.
Lets say 
 
Grid A - Action A - Which Load Data from Table A
Grid B - Action B - Which Load Data from Table B 

Table B reference of Table A.
Currently I am facing a Problem for Transaction .I am managing Transaction using Spring. In Single grid is it OK no issue I faced.
When 2 grid then showing big problem.

In My current Logic If I Update Grid A and Grid B and click Save (for Both Grid only 1 save button) then Grid B will save first in database (Grid B is a Below grid) and after that Grid A will save data in database but at the time saving Grid A data in database in exception will occurred then only Grid A Data will roll-back.Grid B data as it is(Not rollback). because for both Grid Action 
is different .How can I manage it ?
Not getting any solution if any one know please suggest me...

Comment: Facing Same problem...

Comment: If there is **one** save button then there is **one** action for saving, no?

Comment: Aleksandr M Thank you for your reply...But Client requirement is like this.in 1 save button can able to save multiple grid data. we achieve this but transaction issue.

Comment: How do you manage transactions?

Comment: For Transaction i am using Spring and each Struts action I am starting and ending Transaction.is it any way to transfer transaction object to another action transaction class or any other else ?

Comment: In short, the problem is, how to keep transaction active for multiple HTTP requests ? (Manually start and commit/rollback transaction between requests)

Comment: Again: if you transactions are per actions and you have **one** submit button then there is **one** action.

Comment: is it possible to share transaction from 1 action to another action?

Comment: Thankx Aleksandr for your reply .yes ,my action as per transaction .but issue is i am using struts 2 jquery grid plugin which have 1 action per grid .thats why it is difficult to manage.do have any solution ?